# iOS - Constant listening to database update implementation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project where I have 4 tab bars, and when i switched tabs, my api to get the API request to update my view is in the method viewDidAppear().

However this will make a very bad UX experience for user as whenever they switch tab, a loading icon and some times it load for 0.5 seconds but that instant appearance and disappearance of the loading icon is really bad for UX perspective. How can i implement a view where whenever the database value change, my view is automatically updating itself?

I have thought of using Timer() to implement where it calls the api every second but this is not practical as it will be constantly calling the API every second.
Does anyone have any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Use Firebase Cloud Firestore for you Database

Comment: no, why firebase is a solution here? imagine  the architecture does not include firebase in tech stack what will u do, migrate to firebase for this scenario?

Comment: Yes, firebase is not an option here

Comment: To notify client app that the remote data have changed, you can use (optionally background) remote push notifications. This is implemented on the API server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here, but I'll try to provide a generalized answer and point to several possible solutions to the UX problem.

There's several aspects that can play a role here:

1. Do you control the backend the data comes from, i.e. is it possible to follow paiv's comment and implement push notification? Or perhaps use some other means than pure HTTP(S) requests, like a websocket?
2. How frequently does data change? Is it realistic that it does so in between switching from one tab to another?

   - On that note, what do you do when data changes *while your user is on one tab*? Does that get refreshed in any way? Is it a problem if they don't get informed about this immediately? Is there a refresh button?
3. Do you persist the data beyond a view's on-screen time at all? Is it scrapped when a user re-visits a tab, i.e. does a tab always start "empty" until the API response is handled or do users see the values from the last time they visited that tab?

What best to do depends a lot on the exact answers to these questions. If you cannot enable the backend to do anything besides serving HTTP requests AND have to keep all data up-to-date constantly then obviously you have to do something like the polling you described. The update-interval depends on how important this is for your users. Even if it is 1 second, be aware that this means they could visit a tab before the next update has been fetched.

*If* you can adapt the backend *and* up-to-date data is a must, then push notifications or perhaps websockets are a way to go (keep in mind that websockets mean one open-connection per active user then!).
Push notifications would probably break down when the update interval is too high (i.e. if data gets changed in the backend very quickly and you keep spamming them), but would work nicely otherwise, plus they would update views that are already on screen if used correctly.

In 90 % of the cases I've seen, however, going with regular HTTP requests and *a properly designed UI* is the best choice. Properly decoupling the UI code from the data loading code and the code that displays the data is also very important. Here's how I would handle this:

1. Properly persist the data in some way in the app that does not require on views owning the data alone. If you want to persist beyond app runtime that means CoreData (or an equivalent), otherwise an in memory storage may be fine (that is kind of a global state then).
2. In your UI, show *any data you currently have*, even if it is "outdated" (in your case: "left over from the last time the user was on this tab"). Design the UI so that this is clearly apparent (grey it out, put tiny activity indicators next to the data while it is being loaded anew/updated, or something similar).
3. As said in 2. *do* show if the app is loading data. Initiating the loading when the users go to a tab is okay, but don't make a UI that is completely dominated by it (like one giant, empty view with a spinner on it).
4. Functionally, the loading should not directly update any views, instead it writes new data to your storage and just informs views and view controllers that they need to update themselves (if you're using CoreData and/or Combine you get a lot of this logic basically for free, especially for a SwiftUI app).

Such a design also lends itself to later being adapted for push notifications: While at first the re-loading is triggered by a tab switch (or a "refresh" button, for example), once (silent) PNs are available, *they* trigger the reloading. Even websockets can be integrated into this more or less, though there's probably a bit more to do that.

In any way, as said it all depends on your use-case and also available resources, but the gist of it is probably "If the current loading icon you have destroys the UX, redesign it properly". My gut feeling here would be that anything else might be over-engineering for your needs...

Comment: Thank you for your useful info. Appreciate it alot. You pointed out some good points and reference to look into. Once again, thank you for your accepted answer

Comment: You're very welcome, even if I could not give a simple "do this and it works" answer. :) Glad my lengthy elaboration could be of service!